# PHP: Best way to check if input is a valid number?

Tags: php, input, validation, numeric

What is the best way of checking if input is numeric?

- 1-
- +111+
- 5xf
- 0xf

Those kind of numbers should not be valid. Only numbers like: 123, 012 (12), positive numbers should be valid.
This is mye current code:

```
$num = (int) $val;
if (
    preg_match('/^\d+$/', $num)
    &&
    strval(intval($num)) == strval($num)
    )
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: don't make (int) on 1st line in your code! transform it to (string)  then work with strings with ctype_digit($num) will do better than int(proff in manual http://php.net/ctype_digit) !!!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

[`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) was built precisely for this purpose.

Comment: couse in 1st line it **$num = (int) $val;**   if transform to string, **$num = (string) $val;** will be ok, as it typed in manual !!!

Comment: Man, your user is grayed out, would you share with us what did you do?

Answer (score 46):

I use

```
if(is_numeric($value) && $value > 0 && $value == round($value, 0)){
```

to validate if a value is numeric, positive and integral

http://php.net/is_numeric

I don't really like ctype_digit as its not as readable as "is_numeric" and actually has less flaws when you really want to validate that a value is numeric.

Comment: except that the OP is looking for positive integers only, not numerics.

Answer (score 20):

[`filter_var()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

```
$options = array(
    'options' => array('min_range' => 0)
);

if (filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options) !== FALSE) {
 // you're good
}
```

Comment: +1 As this is a more semantic (though more verbose) solution than `ctype_digit`

Answer (score 11):

```
return ctype_digit($num) && (int) $num > 0
```

Answer (score 11):

**For PHP version 4 or later versions:**

```
<?PHP
$input = 4;
if(is_numeric($input)){  // return **TRUE** if it is numeric
    echo "The input is numeric";
}else{
    echo "The input is not numeric";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The most secure way

```
if(preg_replace('/^(\-){0,1}[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){0,1}/', '', $value) == ""){
  //if all made of numbers "-" or ".", then yes is number;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, for example OP's example of "1-" shouldn't be considered a valid number, but according to this regex it is.

Comment: @rowatt the \- is for negative numbers. I changed it to only account for "-" at the begging